# Cookie::get() return null

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, laravel-5

I have problems getting Cookie, I define a cookie in one middleware "CheckReferral", but when I call the cookie in one Controller the cookie return null, I check the cookie in the browser, and the cookie is good in the browser, I don't know what is the problem with the cookie... I've googled too much and this is my last resource, Someone can help me?

Here is the code of the middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CheckReferral
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->hasCookie('referral')) {
            return $next($request);
        } else {
            if ($request->query('ref')) {
                return redirect($request->fullUrl())->withCookie(cookie()->forever('referral', $request->query('ref')));
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

This is how I call the cookie in the controller:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    // $referred_by = User::where( 'affiliate_id', Cookie::get( 'referral' ) )->first();
    // $referred_user = Cookie::get( 'referral' );

    return User::create([
        'name'         => $data['name'],
        'email'        => $data['email'],
        'password'     => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'affiliate_id' => $this->uniqueRandomString(),
        'referred_by'  => Cookie::get('referral'),
    ]);
}
```

Here is the cookie stored in the browser:

[image: Why I can't use this stored?]

Here is the database... the field referred_by, is stored as null, but should store the Value of the cookie:

[image: Why the cookie return null?]

Thank a lot, I hope resolve the problem, and know the cause...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it using vanilla PHP, the global variable `$_COOKIE`

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    // $referred_by = User::where( 'affiliate_id', Cookie::get( 'referral' ) )->first();
    // $referred_user = Cookie::get( 'referral' );

    return User::create([
        'name'         => $data['name'],
        'email'        => $data['email'],
        'password'     => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'affiliate_id' => $this->uniqueRandomString(),
        'referred_by'  => $_COOKIE['referral'],
    ]);
}
```

Where `Cookie::get('referral')` is `$_COOKIE['referral']` is not a Elegant solution, but work...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've defined that middleware in `app\Http\Kernel.php`. Specifically in the `'web'` array there.

Imported the middleware in your `web.php` ( routes ) file.

..and finally added that middleware for your route like so:

```
Route::web('/', ['middleware' => CheckReferral']
```

If you've already done so then make sure you've added `referred_by` column to the `$fillable[]` array of your `User` model.

Edit.
This will do:

```
\Request::cookie('referral');
```

Comment: Yes I've defined the middleware in the kernel, as result the cookie is stored in the browser... and the middleware run globally, not need to be defined in the route... And I've putted in the `$fillable[]` the problem is Cookie::get() return null and I've tested it with the field email, that is not nulable, and I get the error... So, the Problem is the Cookie::get()...

Comment: Please try dumping this if it actually as the value in your middleware. ``$request->query('ref')``

Comment: @Alexcueto updated the answer. \Request::cookie('referral'); will work.

Comment: Can you check if object actually container anything: ``\Cookie::get();``

Comment: I've seen the problem, I've tested with `$_COOKIE` and work, the problem is with `Cookie::get()`